Interpreting the partial derivative of a low-pass filter with respect to its parameter
Looking at the Laplace transform of a single pole low pass filter and its partial derivative with respect to its 'time constant' $\tau$:
$$
\begin{align}
G(s, \tau)=\frac{1}{1+s\tau},&&
\frac{\partial G}{\partial \tau}=\frac{-s}{(1+s\tau)^2}
\end{align}
$$
Plotting these two functions with respect to frequency (below) with a fixed value of $\tau$ I am surprised by the shape of the partial derivative at low frequencies.
A small change to $\tau$ should just shift the filter response (blue line) slightly to the left or right with negligible effect on low frequencies. Hence I would intuitively expect $\frac{\delta G}{\delta \tau}$ at low frequencies to be very small.
Am I calculating the partial derivative wrongly, or is this a problem with how I'm interpreting the results?

EDIT: Here is a linear plot for comparison as suggested in comments. I think the curvature now makes more sense but the scale of the derivative function seems very large.


You're misinterpreting the plot drastically because log log plots alter the curvature and concavity information of the function. And that ultimately is the source of the peaks and other features of the derivative. But like other new contexts you simply need to demolish your old intuition and retool it by trying more examples. It can be helpful to convert this information into a bode plot and see what patterns emerge.

Good point on the distortion introduced by doing a log/log plot @NinadMunshi - I've edited to include a lin/lin plot for comparison. You're right: the curvature now makes more sense. Even so I'm surprised how BIG the partial derivative function is.

Again you don't have a reference for what is big or small because you have never done this before. Don't fall into that trap of preclassifying what is or isn't normal until you get more experience.

Let me give you an example to build intuition. Let's say you have a bode plot that looks like a horizontal line at 20 dB until $\omega_1$, a 20 dB/decade roll off from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_2$, then a flat line at say -20 dB past $\omega_1$. What would you expect the bode plot of the derivative to look like?

OK I just calculated the value of tau, and now it's clear why $\frac{\partial G}{\partial\tau}$ is so big! Thanks for your help @NinadMunshi
